# why open file descriptors are not getting reused instead they are increasing in number value

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

I have a simple C HTTP server. I close file descriptors for disk files and new connection `fd`s returned by `accept(...)`, but I noticed that I am getting new file descriptor numbers that are bigger than the previous numbers: for example file descriptor from accept return starts with 4, then 5, then 4 again and so on until file descriptor reaches max open file descriptor on a system.

I have set the value to `10,000` on my system but I am not sure why exactly file descriptor number jumps to max value. And I am kind of sure than my program is closing the file descriptors.

So I would like to know if there are not thousands of connections then how come file descriptor new number are increasing periodically: in around 24 hours I get message `accept: too many open files`. What is this message?

Also, does `ulimit -n number` value get reset automatically without system reboot?

as mentioned in the answer. The output of `_2$ ps aux | grep lh` is

```
dr-x------ 2 fawad fawad  0 Oct 11 11:15 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 fawad fawad  0 Oct 11 11:15 ..
lrwx------ 1 fawad fawad 64 Oct 11 11:15 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 fawad fawad 64 Oct 11 11:15 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 fawad fawad 64 Oct 11 11:15 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 fawad fawad 64 Oct 11 11:25 255 -> /dev/pts/3
```

and the output of `ls -la /proc/$$/fd` is

```
root       49855  0.5  5.4 4930756 322328 ?      Sl   Oct09  15:58 /usr/share/atom/atom --executed-from=/home/fawad/Desktop/C++-work/lhparse --pid=49844 --no-sandbox
root       80901  0.0  0.0  25360  5952 pts/4    S+   09:32   0:00 sudo ./lh
root       80902  0.0  0.0 1100852 2812 pts/4    S+   09:32   0:00 ./lh
fawad      83419  0.0  0.0  19976   916 pts/3    S+   11:27   0:00 grep --color=auto lh
```

I like to know what is pts/4 etc. column. is this the file descriptor number.

Comment: if you close `fd` properly, linux should reuse fd numbers. use `ls -lh /proc/pid/fd/` to  list opened fds of a process

Comment: Please show us the result of `netstat` for the relevant port(s). It is certain that you *are* leaking `fd`s or socket descriptors, whatever you may thing.

Comment: @user207421 `netstat -p` showing quite many connections in CLOSE_WAIT state. but what the difference between ESTABLISHED and CLOSE_WAIT I am closing close(accept_fd_return) and not closing what returned from `server_fd=socket()` function call

Comment: *Ergo* you have a socket leak. That's what `CLOSE_WAIT` means. You have received end of stream on a socket, and not closed it yourself.

Comment: You got your labels swapped: the first output is from `ls -la /proc/$$/fd` (which was a bad suggestion from hookenz because it shows your shell _not_ the program you want) and the second is from `ps aux | grep lh`. /dev/pts/(number) abbreviated to pts/(number) in `ps` is NOT an fd, it identifies the _terminal session_ (or technically pseudoterminal -- pts is pseudo terminal slave). Your shell has _four_ fds 0,1,2,255 open on one terminal /dev/pts/3, as is common. Similarly you have two processes matching lh (sudo ./lh and ./lh) on pts/4 and a different one (grep ... lh) on pts/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that the socket that is represented by the file descriptor is in close_wait or time_wait state. Which means the TCP stack holds the fd open for a bit longer. So you won't be able to reuse it immediately in this instance.

Once the socket is fully finished with and closed, the file descriptor number will then available for reuse inside your program.

See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Protocol Operation and  specifically Wait States.

To see what files are still open you can run

```
ls -la /proc/$$/fd
```

The output of this will also be of help.

```
ss -tan | head -5
LISTEN     0  511             *:80              *:*
SYN-RECV   0  0     192.0.2.145:80    203.0.113.5:35449
SYN-RECV   0  0     192.0.2.145:80   203.0.113.27:53599
ESTAB      0  0     192.0.2.145:80   203.0.113.27:33605
TIME-WAIT  0  0     192.0.2.145:80   203.0.113.47:50685
```

Comment: A file descriptor cannot be in close_wait or time_wait state. A TCP socket may be in such state. When you close a file descriptor, it is closed. Gone for good. The socket it was attached to may linger on in close_wait or time_wait state.

Comment: Quite correct.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: `It's likely that the socket that is represented by the file descriptor is in close_wait or time_wait state. Which means the OS holds the fd open for a bit longer.` thanks for ur answer and also is there any thing I can do to remove `close_wait` or `time_wait` state behavior. so as the socket closes and after that if a new connection get opened frequently then its assigns the same file descriptor.

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` does not mean that 'the OS holds the fd open for a bit longer'. It means that the local application hasn't closed the socket yet. The OS can't do anything about this. It is *prima facie* evidence of a socket leak, however. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem  Your citation says the same thing. It is therefore incorrect to claim that a file descriptor cannot be in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. It can.

Comment: @user207421 so I am getting the same fd number again and again for sometime like initially my accept fd number starts with 4 then gets to 5 in next request and 4 again. it happens like 8 or 9 times before new number bigger one get assigned. I will look into my code again. but u are saying that what I need to do to first make sure fd closes? are u?

Comment: @user207421 "It means that the local application hasn't closed the socket yet". A file descriptor is either open or closed. There is no CLOSE_WAIT file descriptors. A CLOSE_WAIT socket probably means that the corresponding file descriptor is simply not closed.

Comment: To remove the time wait behavior you can use an abortive close.  Be careful.  Look up what it does and understand why you might or might not want that behavior and why time wait exist.

Comment: @hookenz I called close(accept_fd) . But in case  if Close_waite case what Servers normally do. Should I let the connection in CLOSE_WAIT state or I need to do something in code?

Comment: @user786 If you are getting the same `fd` value again it is evidence of re-use. If you aren't, it is evidence of a leak. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @user207421 so if I call shutdown(accepted_fd) right before close(accepted_fd) then is there any sure thing that fd number will reuse? I'd not then what I need to do. abortive close perhapps?

Comment: @user786. No. `shutdown()` immediately before `close()` is redundant. What you are missing is the `close()` itself: probably in an error path. Desk-check. And please forget about the abortive close option. It doesn't *solve* your resource leak, and it introduces new problems of its own.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. And `linger` has nothing to do with either `CLOSE_WAIT` or `TIME_WAIT`.

Comment: I'm assuming he is calling close.  You need that at both ends.

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` indicates that he isn't calling `close()`. That's what it means. That's *all* it means.